# How do I go about scraping a url from inline javascript

Tags: javascript, scrape

This is repeated 240 times, each time the two sets of the last digits are different numbers, i would like a list of all the urls.

So i suppose i need to find each script and then find the first "commtArr" in each script, assuming its always the first.

Where do I even start?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            commArr[commArr.length] = "http://example.com/index.php?option==down&pid=123&id=389";
            commtArr[commtArr.length] = "mp3";
            commnArr[commnArr.length] = "john doe.mp3";
</script">
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL is actually being inserted into *commArr*, not *commtArr*
It seems *commArr* will only ever have the URL.

Assuming the script is repeated X times on the same page, you're left with a single variable with all the URLs already. 
It's just a simple case of listing it out.

```
for (i = 0; i < commArr.length; i++) { console.log(commArr[i]) }
```

If it's on various pages, then you may need some kind of spider bot script to go to all the pages, run a script that grabs *commArr* and persistently saves it. I'm afraid I can't suggest anything for that aside from doing it manually.